# Removing a Node from a Graph

Tags: python, data-structures, graph, networkx

I made a graph with weights. I am trying to remove Node1. I can remove in console but when I draw the graph, it's still there.

My code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
i=1

#Adding nodes to graph
# "pos" is for the location of the nodes
G.add_node(0,pos=(0,5))
G.add_node(1,pos=(10,0))
G.add_node(2,pos=(5,-5))
G.add_node(3,pos=(-5,-5))
G.add_node(4,pos=(-10,0))

# Adding edges each node
G.add_edge(0,4,weight=2)
G.add_edge(0,1,weight=5)
G.add_edge(0,2,weight=3)


G.add_edge(1,3,weight=6)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=2)

G.add_edge(2,1,weight=1)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=2)

G.add_edge(4,3,weight=4)
G.add_edge(4,2,weight=10)
G.add_edge(4,1,weight=6)

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
list = [nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,1,6),nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,2,10),nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,3,4)]
print((list))

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight', )
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
#print(nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,0))
print("**************")
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
print("Before removing Node 1: ",G.nodes)
print("******************")
G.remove_node(1)
print("After removing Node1: ",G.nodes)

plt.show()
```

Console output:

```
[[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
**************
Before removing Node 1:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
******************
After removing Node1:  [0, 2, 3, 4]
```

My draw:

[image: Graph before remove 1]

How can I draw that graph again after remove Node1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)` again before plotting new graph.
Your code should look like:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
G.remove_node(1) # this line of code remove only vertex, don't forget also remove weights

plt.show()
plt.clf()

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but I get this error after I close the last draw window:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Akif\PycharmProjects\graph\venv\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\digraph.py", line 520, in remove_node
Before removing Node 1:  [0, 2, 3, 4]
******************
    nbrs = self._succ[n]
KeyError: 1
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "C:/Users/Akif/PycharmProjects/graph/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    G.remove_node(1)
  File "C:\Users\Akif\PycharmProjects\graph\venv\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\digraph.py", line 523, in remove_node
    raise NetworkXError(f"The node {n} is not in the digraph.") from e
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node 1 is not in the digraph.

Comment: @MehmetAkifÇelebi that's because you still have edges linked to this node. You should remove them too

Comment: Yes.  I removed them too. Answer is below.

Comment: And I wonder sth:  There are two edges between Node1 and Node2. But I can only see one edge. How can I see both of them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The clearest version is here:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
i=1

#Adding nodes to graph
# "pos" is for the location of the nodes
G.add_node(0,pos=(0,5))
G.add_node(1,pos=(10,0))
G.add_node(2,pos=(5,-5))
G.add_node(3,pos=(-5,-5))
G.add_node(4,pos=(-10,0))

# Adding edges each node
G.add_edge(0,4,weight=2)
G.add_edge(0,1,weight=5)
G.add_edge(0,2,weight=3)


G.add_edge(1,3,weight=6)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=2)

G.add_edge(2,1,weight=1)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=2)

G.add_edge(4,3,weight=4)
G.add_edge(4,2,weight=10)
G.add_edge(4,1,weight=6)

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
list = [nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,1,6),nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,2,10),nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,3,4)]
print((list))
print("Shortest path btwn 4-1:",nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,1),"=",nx.dijkstra_path_length(G,4,1))
print("Shortest path btwn 4-2:",nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,2),"=",nx.dijkstra_path_length(G,4,2))
print("Shortest path btwn 4-3:",nx.dijkstra_path(G,4,3),"=",nx.dijkstra_path_length(G,4,3))

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight', )
print("Before removing Node 1: ",G.nodes)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
plt.clf() #Clears the current figure.

G.remove_node(1) # this line of code remove only vertex, don't forget also remove weights

print("*****************")
print("******************")
print("After removing Node1: ",G.nodes)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels, )
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```